# Fetch all rows of a two column result set as an associative array

Tags: php, sql

My input select is just a select box. I'm using this two column array function(). The definition for the two column array is fairly self explanatory.

Fetch all rows of a two column result set as an associative array.

The first column represents the keys and the second the values. Use this particularly for associative select boxes.

```
,input_select('meter', sql::two_column_array("select a.medicareid, b.DESCRIPTION_ from ev.bo.product_type a 
left outer join PARE.AS.DME b on a.medicareid = b.MEDICAIDID 
where b.medicareid = 'E0607' and b.INACTIVATE != 'Y'"),1)
```

My question is, why am i only returning the last result. result `#71` in my select box.
When i run this is sql studio i'm returning all `71` results. I know the query is correct so i'm assuming it has something to do with it being associative..

I'm using `sql server 2008`, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you recieve an array with only one element?

Comment: Yes. My array only returned one element.

Comment: please do a `print_r` for your result, and add it to your post so we can see what it's generating